# Equivalence condition for equicontinuous family of continuous maps

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Assume that $(, d)$ is a metric space with metric , and let $$ be a set of mappings from
 into itself. The family  $F$ is called equicontinuous if for every $\epsilon>0$, there is $\delta>0$ such that
$$d(x, y)<\delta\Rightarrow  d(f(x), f(y))<\epsilon, \forall f\in F.$$

Theorem A.10.3 in [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0138MAL3W):

Let $$ be a compact metric space and let $\subseteq  ^$. Then the following
conditions are equivalent:

$(i)$ $$ is equicontinuous on $$;

$(ii)$ $\subseteq ( ,)$ and $$ has a compact closure in $_u(,)$

$(iii)$ For every $\epsilon>0$  there is a finite subset $$ of $$ with the following property:
$$\forall f\in F, \exists g\in K :
((), ()) < \epsilon, \forall x\in X. $$

In this book, it is proved that $(iii)\Rightarrow (i)\Rightarrow (ii)\Rightarrow (iii)$

But, in my research, I need to prove $(i)\Leftrightarrow (iii)$. Please help me to know it.

In the following, I give proof of $(iii)\Rightarrow (i)$ from ([1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0138MAL3W)).

Let $\epsilon>0$ and select $$ according to $(iii)$. As the set $$ is finite, it is
equicontinuous on $$: if $_0\in $ then there is a nbd $$ of $_0$ such that
$((), (_0)) < \epsilon$
for all $x\in U$ and all $g\in K$. If $f\in F$ then select $g$ according to $(iii)$; then for every $x\in U$
one has
$((), (_0)) ≤ ((), ()) + ((), (_0)) + ((_0), (_0))\leq 3\epsilon$.
So  is equicontinuous at the (arbitrary) point $_0$. This proved $(iii)\Rightarrow (i)$.

I am so thankfull if you give a direct proof for $(i)\Rightarrow (iii)$.

Comment: That $\text{(iii)} \implies \text{(i)} \implies \text{(ii)}\implies\text{(iii)}$ is a proof that $\text{(i)} \iff \text{(iii)}$. What is wrong with that proof? Why must you avoid showing $\text{(ii)}$ while proving $\text{(i)} \implies \text{(iii)}$?

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks, yes I know that it is a proof. But  in this proof used closure of $F$ and .. . But, I would like to know can I give a equivalent condition for equicontinuous point $p\in X$ for $F$? By proof $(iii)\Rightarrow (i)$, we can show that if for every $\epsilon>0$ there is an open set $U$ of $p$ and finite set $K$ of $F$ such that for every $f\in F$ there is $g\in K$ such that $d(f(z), g(z))<\epsilon$ for all $z\in U$, then $p\in X$ is equicontious point for $F$.

Comment: I would like to know that the converse does hold?

Comment: So ... you want to limit (i) to only equicontinuity at a fixed point $p$, and from it show what? (iii) itself is full equicontinuity on $X$, and equicontinuity at a point is not going to be sufficient to prove equicontinuity everywhere. Maybe you want to prove that for all for $\epsilon > 0$ there is a finite $K \subseteq F$ such that $\forall f \in F, \exists g\in K, d(f(p), g(p)) < \epsilon$? That follows from $(i)$ and the compactness of the codomain of the functions $X$. But you used more of the hypothesis of (iii) than this includes.